# Games.Snapshots.open: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Since moving to SavedGames I get the following exception across multiple:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.jx.a(jx.java:0)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.b(c.java:0)
       at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl.open(SnapshotsImpl.java)
```

This is the call which invokes this exception:

```
Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result = Games.Snapshots.open(googleApiClient, snapshotName, true).await();
```

The result is that at least some users can't sync their game progress between devices. We can catch the exception but sync between devices doesn't work anymore.